# What is this star-like delicate pink flower?

Tags: identification, wildflowers

This flower makes me stop and look at it and admire its strange combination of frailty and firmness.

Do you know the name of the flower?

[image]

The photo is from previous years, probably taken in mid-summer.

Comment: where's it growing - in the wild or in someone''s garden?

Comment: In someone's garden, but that garden is intentionally filled with wildflowers. I found Clarkia pulchella on the internet, it may be a cousin of this flower. @Bamboo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [*Lychnis flos-cuculi*](http://www.luontoportti.com/suomi/en/kukkakasvit/ragged-robin), also known as ragged robin.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed looks like the one from the picture.

Comment: And this is the second plant that I heard of with such rhythmic three-part name. The first was Crataegus crus-galli.

Comment: Hey Vivid - here's another rhythmic three-parter for you: Gleditsia triacanthos inermis (Honey Locust tree)

Comment: What strange name. For me it is still `Silene flos-cuculi` (just added for reference). I would say it is not infrequent on not-manured open fields in Europe. I find also `Adiantus capillus-veneris` rhythmic (3 syllabi each, easy to pronounce).